# Get application version always return 1.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, version

I want to show the application version in my application. I did some research and I tried this:

```
 System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 Version version = assembly.GetName().Version;
 _applicationVersion = version.Major + "." + version.Minor + "." + version.Build;
```

But my version variable always shows 1.0.0.0

When I publish my application and I install it on my computer it shows in my program list that it's version 1.0.1.1. Which is the number I expect my application to show

Does anybody has a solution for this?

**EDIT**

My problem was that I was just setting the publish version in the properties of my visual studio project. Which doesn't seem to be the application version you get from the code I posted above. I've found the AssemblyInfo.cs file which also has 2 attributes:

```
   [assembly: AssemblyVersion("x.x.x.x")]
   [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("x.x.x.x")]
```

So that solved my first problem.

But what is the difference between those 2 version numbers, why do you want to have 2 different versions? And what does the publish version stand for?

Isn't there always just 1 version number for an application?

Comment: Where are you using the above code? If you need exe version you need `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` instead of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`

Comment: Why are you generating only three numbers but quote four in your question?  What is a "program list"?  What is your [AssemblyFileVersion]?